# Saving Rails associations after creating User

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I'm new to Rails and ActiveRecord and need some help. Basically, I have 4 models: `User`, `Property`, `PropertyAccount`, and `AccountInvitation`. Users and Properties have a many to many relationship via `PropertyAccounts`. `AccountInvitations` have a user's email and a `property_id`.

What I want to happen is that after a user registers on my app, his user account is automatically associated with some pre-created Properties. What I don't know how to do is write the query to get the Property objects from the AccountInvitations and save them to the User object. Please see **`def assign_properties`** for my pseudo code. Any help is welcome, thanks so much!

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :property_accounts
  has_many :properties, through: :property_accounts
  after_create :assign_properties

  # Check to see if user has any pre-assigned properties, and if so assign them
  def assign_properties
    account_invitations = AccountInvitations.where(email: self.email)

    if account_invitations.any?
      account_invitations.each do |i|
        properties += Property.find(i.property_id)
      end
      self.properties = properties
      self.save
    end
  end
end

class AccountInvitation < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :property
    validates  :property_id, presence: true
    validates  :email, uniqueness: {scope: :property_id}
end

class Property < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :account_invitations
  has_many :property_accounts
  has_many :users, through: :property_accounts
end

class PropertyAccount < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :property
  belongs_to :user
end
```

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to @wangthony , I looked at the `includes` method on http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods/includes and tweaked one of their examples in order to get this to work. Here's the solution:

```
def assign_property
  self.properties = Property.includes(:account_invitations).where('account_invitations.email = ?', self.email).references(:account_invitations)
  self.save
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can do this:

```
user.properties = Property.includes(:account_invitations).where(email: user.email)
user.save
```

Comment: I get this error: ERROR:  column properties.email does not exist
LINE 1: SELECT "properties".* FROM "properties" WHERE "properties"."email" = 'test...

Comment: After some sleuthing, the answer was here: [API Dock](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods/includes) and this was their example: `User.includes(:posts).where('posts.name = ?', 'example').references(:posts)` ... thanks for the tip @wangthony

Comment: anytime -- glad you found the solution, @John!